# Can I override the Mongoid push (i.e. <<) method for has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Lets say that I had a class

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :bars
end
```

Is there any way to override `some_foo.bars.push(some_bars)`?  Mostly I want to put in some business logic before calling the parent `#push`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extensions which allow you to add/override methods for the relation.

From the [Mongoid Docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common):

> #### Extensions
>
> All relations can have extensions, which provides a way to add application specific functionality to the relation. They are defined by providing a block to the relation definition.

There you can override the `:<<` method and use `super` to call the original:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :bars do
    def <<(obj)
      puts 'called'
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Be careful though with putting important things in there, because it's easy to create `Bar`s without using the `:<<`-method: `Bar.create! foo: some_foo` would skip your business logic.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to reference the Foo instance from within the `:<<` method?

Comment: Just found the answer, there are instance variables `@base` and `@target` which get generated. `@base` is what I want